# NoReset and FullReset in Appium

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

What does noReset or FullReset do in Appium? Need a good understanding on that? Itried to set in DesiredCapabalities and in Appium but was not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noReset if set to TRUE would reset the app data, i.e. it will clear app data.

fullReset if set to TRUE uninstalls the app.

Check this link for details - https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps.md

Comment: What is App data ? is it like Username, password used previously?

Comment: Why do we need to do a norest or fullRest?

Comment: Most of the apps (I think) use a local database on which they store your data, so that the app doesn't need to fetch this data everytime from the server. This can be username password as well as other data, for example in facebook it can store some of your posts as well. So reset will clear this app data as well as cache data.

Comment: I haven't myself used noReset or fullReset, but one situation where you can use it is for reinstalling the new versions of the app. When your app is in dev stage, there might be newer builds coming out almost everyday. In such a scenario, you can set your scripts to run in fullReset mode, so that it uninstalls the app and reinstalls again during every run. This way you can avoid the manual process of reinstalling the new versions of the app. This works with iOS where Appium can install the app from ipa file. With Android, the app can be installed using ADB commands.

Answer (score 12):

Check the documentation:

1. http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/
2. http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/index.html

The accepted answer is not correct.

If noReset is set to TRUE, the app data will NOT be cleared before this session starts.

If fullReset is set to true, the app will get uninstalled and all data will be cleared.

Comment: Do you know the default values of these caps? I checked the docs couldn't find it.

Comment: Check the second link from the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I still didn't see the default values for `fullReset` and `noReset `

Comment: check the default tab

Comment: That documentation is, at present, incoherent.  The default *column* of the table describes *behavior*, not a default settting (true or false values) for each of the two capabilities.  And since the "default" behaviors are not described quite the same way as the entries for the capabilities (which presumably describe the behavior when set to "true", though this isn't stated), it is not easy to see what is implied about the default values for "fullReset" and "noReset' capability.   I think if you read the behaviors and puzzle it out, you can see the default for each capability is "false".

Comment: This is one where the *only* way to know just what these flags do is to read the Appium source code.  Hints:

This (but not web docs) confirms these flags are mutually exclusive: https://github.com/appium/appium-base-drive/blob/a908e8127829f19ee27347e926ab30abe282f6ed/lib/basedriver/commands/session.js#L59

For Android, "fullReset" default is false and that flag interacts with "skipInstall" capability, which the web docs don't tell you (https://github.com/appium/appium-uiautomator2-driver/blob/84dd6d00228cbe7ec7de44a1f89ac9316254af8b/lib/driver.js).